# bubble effect with share buttons

Tags: javascript, css, sharing, addthis

I could find tutorial and code for bubble effect with CSS and static images:  http://aext.net/example/bubble-css

I have also put together various sharing buttons to make a sharing bar:
http://pollwidget.org/test.html

My question is, how do I create a sharing bar with bubble effect? Because all these working buttons are got from embedding a javascript code from twitter etc, while the bubble effect is with static images.

I am not looking for complete source code, but some hints and tips to get me started would be appreciated.

Comment: http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/ -> is this the kind of bubble effect you need with all social buttons intact so that user can post anything to multiple networks ?

Comment: thanks Ravi. Its not speech bubble I am looking for. I want something like : http://aext.net/example/bubble-css  but with the share functionality working.

Comment: to achieve the mac dockbar effect you can use image swapping or css sprites technique as I have mentioned in my answer.
you can setup click handlers once above is done and direct them appropriately to a different logic for sharing. twitter gives out an official javascript bookmarklet itself. only thing is you will have to show a box to the user that contains what would be posted to the share network.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it would be possible or wise considering they aren't images, they're individual widgets from various external sources built in HTML/CSS/JS.

You might be able to achieve something along the lines of a bubble effect if you customise an AddThis toolbox - http://www.addthis.com/help/toolbox